# How do I delete a folder from Firebase Storage using a function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I've got a program that regularly uploads files to Firebase Storage and I would like to delete them all at a set time. How would I write a function to delete them all? My files are all stored in a directory called images/

[image: Screenshot of file structure]

Comment: You can use the Cloud Storage list API to iterate each file and delete them independently. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`getFiles()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) method of a Bucket, with a [`GetFilesOptions`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#GetFilesOptions) parameter, in order to loop over all the files, as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.justAnExampleOfCloudFunction = functions.firestore
    .document("/triggeringCollection/{docId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
        const imagesFilesArray = await bucket.getFiles({ directory: 'images' });
        const files = imagesFilesArray[0];

        const promises = [];

        files.forEach(f => {
            promises.push(f.delete());
        })

        await Promise.all(promises);

        return null;

    });
```